# How to authenticate using Twitter in Windows phone 8.1?

Tags: twitter, oauth, windows-phone-8.1

I have the following code for Login Authentication via Twitter in my Windows Phone 8.1 application:

`user = App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Twitter);`

But in wp8.1 LoginAsync method requires 2 parameters and the second parameter should be: `JObject token` where `token` is a `Provider specific object with existing OAuth token to log in with`

What should I enter as a second parameter?
An object of JObject class with the Twitter Access Keys?
If so, how do I assign the keys to the object?

Answer (score 0):

The token object needs to be formatted depending on the specific provider. These are some examples of formats based on the providers:

`MicrosoftAccount
{"authenticationToken":"<authentication_token>"}
Facebook
{"access_token":"<access_token>"}
Google
{"access_token":"<access_token>"}
Azure Active Directory
{"access_token":"<access_token>"}`

I took this information from: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn296411.aspx

So maybe something like

`user = App.MobileService.LoginAsync(
               MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Twitter, 
               "{"access_token":"<access_token>"}");`

EDIT: yeah you're right. it can't be a string

`JObject obj = JObject.Parse(@"{"access_token":"<access_token>"}");`

`user = App.MobileService.LoginAsync(
               MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Twitter, obj);`

Comment: second parameter cant be a string but

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TwitterAutherino](https://github.com/konradbartecki/TwitterAutherino) to integrate Sign in with Twitter button

I am the author of this library, so let me know if you need some non-existent features or some explanation on tutorials